# Custom Camera X inside Activity/Fragment Error ( requires 'compileSdkVersion' set to 32 or higher)

Tags: android, camera, androidx, android-camera2

So I've been trying to create a custom camera inside an activity/fragment using CameraX. As at now, the latest version of that family of cameras (androidx.camera...) is 1.2.0-alpha02. So I update them from 1.1.0-beta01 (which was not working by the way threw an AbstractMethodError at the bindToLifeCycle function

`cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
// Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

```
        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinderBack.surfaceProvider)
            }

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            // AbstractMethodError is thrown by bindToLifecycle
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview)

        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(con!!))`)
```

if anyone has a solution to this, I'd be happy to use the old version of cameras.

Anyway, after updating the versions, I run the sync and it ends up failing to scynrchonize for the following reason...

> Dependency 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.0-alpha02' requires
> 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher. Compilation target for
> module ':app' is 'android-31'

Answer (score 0):

Within your build.gradle you need to set compileSDK / targetSDK to 32. You may also need to update your buildTools version too if you have that set.

Something like this, you may need to change this as this is for KTS:

```
android {
    compileSdk = 32
    buildToolsVersion = "32.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion = 32
}
```